# SQL Database design - three tables: product, sales order, and purchase order - how to store product quantity?

Tags: mysql, database

I have three tables: `product`, `sales_order` (where I sell products) and `purchase_order` (where I buy products). Now I can think of two ways of keeping the quantity of each product:

1. Have a column in the `product` table called `quantity`; when inserting into `sales_order`, I subtract the quantity; when inserting into `purchase_order`, I add the quantity
2. Instead of storing the quantity in the `product` table, I calculate the quantity from the `sales_order` and the `purchase_order` table each time I need to get the `product` table

I am wondering if the second approach is preferable to the first one? I like the second one more because it doesn't store any redundant data; however, I am not so sure if calculating the quantity every time is a bit too much calculation. I am wondering what is the convention and best practice here? Thank you!

Comment: @Strawberry yes, thanks. I will change it to sales_order

Comment: Store the quantity you purchase in purchases. Store the quantity you sell in sales. Or have a transactions table which stores both

Answer (score 0):

I would use the first one. Add a column to the product table in the coding u code -x amount when order and you would then display this in the order table. You could right a script for when the products get to a certain amount it emails you and tells u to replenish stocks. However the second would also work and sql is very powerful so i wouldnt wprry about it being ro demanding as it will prbably work it out faster than we can lol

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the first one because in-memory calculations are faster than issuing select statements to check the sales orders and purchase orders assuming that the number of times the quantity value is retrieved is significantly more than the number of times the quantity value is updated.